# how let a signup, only with a checkbox (terms and conditions) is checked in a gsp grails

Tags: html, grails, checkbox

```
<g:form.....   />
<div class="checkbox">
    <g:checkBox name="myCheckbox"/> <g:message code="view.signup.preTermsInfo"/> <a href="#"><g:messagecode="view.signup.termsInfo"/></a><br/>
</div>

<g:submitButton name="signup" disabled="true" class="btn btn-info" value="${message(code:'form.signup.submit')}" />
```

I need that only when myCheckbox is checked, I can click in submitButton and do a signup. If I try click when myCheckbox is unchecked, do a flash and don't let do a signup.

A solution:

> script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
>
> > ```
> >      function isCheckedTerms(){<br>
> >             var checkTerms = document.getElementById("myCheckbox").checked;
> >             if (checkTerms==true){
> >                 document.getElementById("signup").disabled = false
> >             } else {
> >                 document.getElementById("signup").disabled = true
> >         }
> > ```
> >
> > /script>

```
<g:checkBox name="myCheckbox" onchange="isCheckedTerms()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use build in JQuery plugin.

```
 $("#myCheckbox").click(function() { $("#signup").attr("disabled", !this.checked); });
```